# Graphloader for JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I am building a small graph DB by hand, which will undergo many changes as the graph grows. To maintain the graph in edge and vertex CSV files. I currently have a python script which reads the edge and vertex files and loads the data one element at a time. 
I found that DataStax Enterprise Graph has a [*graphloader* tool](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html) but I could not find something equivalent for JanusGraph. Is there any package which can help in the loading of data from CSV/JSON files into JanusGraph that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any specific tool to do that. You will need to write a small script to parse the csv and load vertexes and edges. You may look into this project https://github.com/IBM/janusgraph-utils or into this [blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/powers-of-ten-part-i) to get you going.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, these scripts give me a better idea on how to store the information in files and load it into the DB.